# Задача с функциями, Python

Tags: python, функции

Проходим функции по основам, ментор объяснил на простейших примерах. Не знаю как сделать так чтобы пользователь ввел число 5 раз, буду благодарна если кто-нибудь объяснит или направит.

Сама задача:

Создайте функцию, которая принимает 2 целых числа. По системе координат x и y, где x - 1 вводимое число, y - второе вводимое число. Ваша задача написать функцию, где пользователь вводит два числа 5 раз и надо определить, где находится ваша текущая позиция. Старт дан с координатами (0, 0).
Формат ввода 2 числа. Формат вывода список из 2 аргументов.

Пример ввода:
1
1

2
3

4
3

5
10

7
15

Результат:
[19, 32]

Comment: Во-первых, *пользователь вводит два числа 5 раз* – какие два числа? Точнее, что эти числа значат? Новые координаты? Значения, которые необходимо прибавить (отнять/умножить/...) к текущим координатам? Поставьте задачу верно. Во-вторых: функции проходите, а до циклов не дошли ещё? Такой себе ментор, видимо.

Comment: Значения нужно прибавить, прошли while и for

Comment: Если прошли `while` и `for` то почему возникает вопрос, как повторить какое-либо действие нужное количество раз? Циклы ведь для этого и предназначены. Если не знаете, как именно написать это в коде (что, опять же, странно, если Вы их проходили), приложите к вопросу свой код (прямо в вопрос, не по ссылке и не картинкой), тогда смогу написать Вам, как это должно выглядеть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Не знаю как сделать так чтобы пользователь ввел число 5 раз, буду благодарна если кто-нибудь объяснит или направит.*
Ну например так. В цикле `while` вводить значения, и выполнять ввод пока число итераций меньше 5.

```
n = 0
x = 0
y = 0
while n <5:
    x_y = input().split()
    x += int(x_y[0])
    y += int(x_y[1])
    n+=1

print([x,y])
```

Comment: input().split(), я не знала что так можно, значительно упростили мне задачу

Answer (score 0):

В дополнение к ответу товарища *Vadim.Sharoikin*

Думаю, здесь более рационально будет использовать `for` вместо `while`

```
x = 0
y = 0
for _ in range(5):
    x_y = input().split()
    x += int(x_y[0])
    y += int(x_y[1])
    n+=1

print([x,y])
```

Comment: Если `number` не используется, то лучше вместо него вставить `_`: `for _ in range(5):` :)

Comment: @gil9red, спасибо, исправил